# Does skooma exist in ESO?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Does skooma exist as an in-game item in Elder Scrolls Online? I've heard conversations about "sugar fiends" in Mistral, but no other mentions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does exist in a side quest. Other than that, it is not available for general consumption. You will have to go with some other catnip brand instead.

Here is a video about this side quest:

Contains spoilers, obviously.